# Activate/ Deactivate CheckBox Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, checkbox

I have made a form with some fields, buttons and a checkbox as shown below.
When the user checks the checkbox, Finish button is activated and Next button is deactivated. 
If the user unchecks the checkbox I want the reverse functionality to begin. 
Finish button deactivated and Next button activated.

My code so far:

```
checkbox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (checkbox.isSelected()){
                flag = 1;
                btnFinish.setEnabled(true);
                btnNext.setEnabled(false);
            }           
        }        
     });
```

Comment: add an `else` block to do the reverse operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the else part to do the inverse your action, this should help you :

```
if (checkbox.isSelected()) {
    flag = 1;
    btnFinish.setEnabled(true);
    btnNext.setEnabled(false);
} else {
    flag = 1;
    btnFinish.setEnabled(false);
    btnNext.setEnabled(true);
}
```